# How to display the SharePoint page title?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, css

When I view my SharePoint site in developer mode, I'm able to see the title. But used class name as **ms-hidden**.

Maybe because of this page title is not visible. I don't know to edit code in the master page.

Please tell me the code I can paste in the script editor. Or please help with other solutions to display the page title. I tried with the below code, but it is not helping.

```
<style type="text/css">  
   .ms-core-pageTitle {  
      display: inline;  
   }  
</style>
```

The actual code in SharePoint is as below:

Some Title

  
  

    
       
    
    

    
    //

Comment: Is page title is hidden for this particular page or all pages in SharePoint site? If it is hidden for the particular page then can you please check from where it is adding CSS to hide it??

Comment: Yes, like Ganesh said, please check if page title is hidden just for a particular page. In addition, are you using Classic page or modern page? Please provide a screen about your page in Developer mode with selecting page title element.